# Clear grid with static and dynamic columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid where I am adding a couple of columns into the template field through the aspx page.

```
      <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnDown" runat="server" CommandName="Download" Text="Download"></asp:LinkButton>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkBtnMan" runat="server" CommandName="Manual" Text="Manual"
                            Style="margin-left: 10px"></asp:LinkButton>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
```

The grid displays search result from a table and there are a few columns that I have to hide, such as the filename column etc, but I do need the data...so I hide them using css styles.

```
    private void generateSearchGrid(DataTable dt)
    {
        if (dt == null || dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            return;
        dgvSearchResults.DataSource = dt;
        dgvSearchResults.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        BoundField bfName = new BoundField();
        bfName.DataField = dt.Columns["OsmProjectName"].ToString();
        bfName.HeaderText = "Project Name";

        BoundField bfProjID = new BoundField();
        bfProjID.DataField = dt.Columns["OsmProjectID"].ToString();
        bfProjID.HeaderText = "ID";


        BoundField bfProjFile = new BoundField();
        bfProjFile.DataField = dt.Columns["OsmProjectFile"].ToString();
        bfProjFile.HeaderText = "Project File";

        BoundField bfProjManual = new BoundField();
        bfProjManual.DataField = dt.Columns["OsmProjectManual"].ToString();
        bfProjManual.HeaderText = "Project Manual";

        BoundField bfProjType = new BoundField();
        bfProjType.DataField = dt.Columns["OsmProjectType"].ToString();
        bfProjType.HeaderText = "Project Type";

        dgvSearchResults.Columns.Add(bfProjID);
        dgvSearchResults.Columns.Add(bfName);
        dgvSearchResults.Columns.Add(bfProjType);

        // WARNING : Keep these two at the end all the time in the same order.
        dgvSearchResults.Columns.Add(bfProjFile);
        dgvSearchResults.Columns.Add(bfProjManual);

        dgvSearchResults.DataBind();

        // Assigning a css where display has been set to none.
        bfProjManual.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "hiddenCols";
        bfProjID.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "hiddenCols";
        bfProjFile.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "hiddenCols";
        bfProjManual.ItemStyle.CssClass = "hiddenCols";
        bfProjID.ItemStyle.CssClass = "hiddenCols";
        bfProjFile.ItemStyle.CssClass = "hiddenCols";
    }
```

At the beginning of every search button click event I refresh the grid by,

```
        dgvSearchResults.DataSource = null;
        dgvSearchResults.DataBind();   
        dgvSearchResults.Columns.Clear();
```

But this clears all the columns including the ones that I bound in the aspx page..as expected. If I don't clear them, the columns from the search result just keeps piling up.

Is there a way where I can clear only the columns bound dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many you've added in the aspx page and how many you add dynamically you could do this.

```
//if total added in aspx page is 2, first one is in index 0, second in index 1

dgvSearchResults.Columns.RemoveAt(2); // this will remove the 3rd column
dgvSearchResults.Columns.RemoveAt(3); // this will remove the 4th columns
// you can continue till column x
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to [disable viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate.aspx) of *dgvSearchResults* GridView. In this case, every postback, you need to bind *dgvSearchResults* with data. If you will not bind, dynamically added columns will be removed automatically (not persisted).

This will happen because in your case, dynamically added data (and also columns) are kept postback to postback in hidden element (viewstate).

So this will become:

```
   private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if(IsPostBack) // If postback, then bind GridView with previous search result
      {
         dgvSearchResults.DataSource = Session["dgvSearchResultsData"];
         dgvSearchResults.DataBind();
      }
   }


   private void generateSearchGrid(DataTable dt)
   {
       // ...
       Session["dgvSearchResultsData"] = dt; // Save result into session
       dgvSearchResults.DataSource = dt;
       // ...
   }
```

*ASPX:*

```
<asp:GridView EnableViewState="false"> ... </GridView>
```